# Quebrar linha automaticamente na exportação para o Excel pelo Delphi

Tags: delphi, microsoft-excel

Estou fazendo uma exportação para o Excel utilizando o Delphi.
Em certo momento, um texto acaba sendo maior que o tamanho da célula, "estourando" seu conteúdo para fora da célula ao abrir o arquivo .XLSX gerado.

Gostaria de saber o comando utilizado para aplicar o efeito do botão "Quebrar Texto Automaticamente" pelo Delphi.

Segue o comando para gerar o texto na célula:

```
Sheet.Range['M' + IntToStr(iLin)] := sTexto;
```

Essa variável `sTexto` guarda uma concatenação de várias linhas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a função [WrapText](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.SysUtils.WrapText), definindo o número máximo de caracteres por linha que você deseja e ele retornara a string com as quebras de linhas necessárias.

```
Uses
  System.SysUtils;

...    
CaracteresPorLinha := 40;
Sheet.Range['M' + IntToStr(iLin)] := WrapText(sTexto, CaracteresPorLinha);
...
```

Comment: Muito obrigado! Deu certo e ficou excelente!!!